# How do I get my border to change back to black when I've dropped it and how do I make sure that it doesn't leave the screen?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Right now, my div moves when I click on it and it turns green, but I can't figure out how to make it go back to black when I'm no longer dragging it. Also, how do I make sure that it doesn't leave the screen?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Q1.css">
<title>Q1</title>

<script>
window.onload = function(){

draggable('rectangle');

};


var dragObj = null;

function draggable(id)
{
var obj = document.getElementById(id);
obj.style.position = "absolute";
obj.onmousedown = function(){
        dragObj = obj;
        obj.style.borderColor = "#00FF00";
}
}

document.onmouseup = function(e){
dragObj = null;
};

document.onmousemove = function(e){
var x = e.pageX;
var y = e.pageY;

if(dragObj == null)
    return;

dragObj.style.left = x +"px";
dragObj.style.top= y +"px";
};


</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="rectangle"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: maybe include a codepen or jsfiddle that people can mess around with. that would make it much easier/quicker to provide you with an answer ;)

Answer (score 0):

To the border color:

```
obj.onmouseup = function(){
        dragObj = null;
        obj.style.borderColor = "#000";
}
```

To the screen limit:

```
I don't know.
```

Comment: No, I've tried it earlier and it unfortunately doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Change your current code to this.

```
obj.onmousedown = function(){
    dragObj = obj;
    obj.style.border-color = "#000000";
}
```

and

```
document.onmousemove = function(e){
    var x = e.pageX;
    var y = e.pageY;

    if (x < 0) x = 0;
    if (x > window.innerWidth) x = window.innerWidth;
    if (y < 0) y = 0;
    if (y > window.innerHeight) y = window.innerHeight;

    if(dragObj == null)
        return;

    dragObj.style.left = x +"px";
    dragObj.style.top= y +"px";
};
```

Comment: Thank you, that was really helpful! Do you by any chance know how to get the border to change to green as I drag it and then back to black when I'm no longer clicking on it?

Comment: Hi, I just updated my answer. Use `border-color` instead of `borderColor`.

Comment: @UniStudent there is a much more precise way to make sure the entire element always remains within view. you can use the method `getBoundingClientRect` to return the position of the top, right, bottom, and left sides of the lement. i've made an edit to Vlav's answer. hopefully he accepts it.